# Geometry nodes - scaling object

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to change the scale of an object "Cube" in accordance of the subdivide level ?
I used a grid of 8x8 vertex and instance cubes on it.
Example : if level 2 then scale cube 0.5, or level 4 then scale 0.25

Thanks for your help.
Rob

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using math node:

[image]

(Whis will not work at level 0, because it would be division by 0)